# Android application - Is Parse a good option?

Tags: android, parse-platform, mbaas

I'm developing a simple application that I'm planning to release to the market. The application will require **at least weekly updates**.

I'm planning to use **Parse** for the backend communication and data storage and exchange. But maybe I was thinking that it is a bit too much complex for my needs.

Basically, at least weekly, the app needs to send a request to the server, get an object (array or list) and if the the obtained object if different from the local copy of same object, the application updates the local copy with the new values.

Do you recommend using Parse for this specific case ? Should I choose another method/tool ? If yes, what are the best options ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: as a side note, Parse handles the sync/update part for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do your hand-made solution, but Parse is a good option to take into account. Maybe it'll be an overkill and storing simple file somewhere in dropbox or on any other CDN is enough for your case, but setting up another service is the task of same complexity.

Moreover, if this values are set manually, then you can use https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#config which incapsulates all update/compare logic inside it.